# Saving PysparkML model in AWS Glue environment into S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, machine-learning, pyspark, model, save

I have trained a PysparkML model in AWS Glue environment. How can I save the trained model into S3 bucket and also upload model from corresponding S3 bucket?